# Does joining Diamond Division restrict you from winning Gold Division awards?

Tags: call-of-duty-ghosts

Half my clan has 3/4 body parts of the Red Uniform Set and we're interested in joining Diamond Division. In case we do join the Diamond Division, would we be capable of winning 1st item of the Yellow Uniform set and 4th item of the Red Uniform Set (for those who don't have it)?